# Interaction has already been acknowledged when using a different button

Tags: discord.js

I am getting the interaction has already been acknowledged error. Basically when the command is called the first time, the button and the modal work just fine. The second time, the button appears but then shows the modal and throws the "DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged." error. I am in a real slump.

```
} else if (order == "edit") {
          let shelfNameSpaces = "";
          for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            shelfNameSpaces += args[i] + " ";
          }
          let shelfName = shelfNameSpaces.trim();
          let shelfObj = await Shelves.findOne({name: shelfName})
          if (shelfObj) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("#0099ff")
              .setThumbnail(profileImage)
              .setTitle(`${shelfObj["name"]}`)
              .setDescription("Displaying shelf info")
              .addField("Owner", `<@${shelfObj["owner"]}>`)
            if (shelfObj["info"].length <= 0) {
              embed.addField("Info", "No information added")
            } else {
              embed.addField("Info", shelfObj["info"])
            }
            let m = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })

            const row = new MessageActionRow();
            row.addComponents(
              new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId(`edit-shelf`)
                .setLabel('Edit Shelf')
                .setStyle("PRIMARY")
            )
            var buttons = await message.channel.send({ components: [row] })
            setTimeout(() => {
              if (buttons.deletable)
                buttons.delete()
            }, 60000);
            // client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
              
              // module.exports = {
              //   name: 'interactionCreate',
              //   async execute (interaction) {
                  
              //   }
              // }
              var editInfo, modal, editRow;
              client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
                if (!interaction.isButton() || interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
                if (interaction.customId == "edit-shelf") {
                  // interaction.reply("Editing")
                  if (buttons.deletable)
                    buttons.delete()
                  modal = new Modal()
                    .setCustomId(`editModal`)
                    .setTitle('Edit Info')
                
                  editInfo = new TextInputComponent()
                    .setCustomId(`editInput`)
                    .setLabel("Input your edit")
                    .setValue(shelfObj["info"])
                    .setStyle("PARAGRAPH")
      
                  editRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(editInfo)
                  modal.addComponents(editRow)
                  await interaction.showModal(modal)
                  modalCheck++;
                }
              })
              client.on("interactionCreate", async (inter) => {
                if (!inter.isModalSubmit()) return;
                inter.deferUpdate()
                const editval = inter.fields.getTextInputValue('editInput')
                // console.log(editval);
                shelfObj["info"] = editval

                const updatedShelf = new Shelves(shelfObj);
                await updatedShelf.save()

                const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor("#0099ff")
                  .setThumbnail(profileImage)
                  .setTitle(`${shelfObj["name"]}`)
                  .setDescription("Displaying shelf info")
                  .addField("Owner", `<@${shelfObj["owner"]}>`)
                if (shelfObj["info"].length <= 0) {
                  embed2.addField("Info", "No information added")
                } else {
                  embed2.addField("Info", shelfObj["info"])
                }
                m.edit({ embeds: [embed2] })
                // inter.reply("Shelf edited successfully")
                // await inter.deleteReply()
                // if (buttons.deletable)
                //   buttons.delete()
              })

              
            } else {
              const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#ff0000")
                .setTitle("Shelves")
                .setDescription("Unknown Shelf")
                .addField("Error", "Shelf not found");
              message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this error multiple times, and I finally found out how to fix this error.

To start off, you need to install a package called nanoid (`npm i nanoid` in terminal).

At the top of your file, include `const { nanoid } = require("nanoid");`. This package is used for creating unique IDs for anything you'd like.

now, make a variable, and make it the following:

```
let id = `button-${nanoid()}`;
```

Make your `.setCustomId()` equal `.setCustomId(id)`.
Lastly, make your `if (interaction.customId == "edit-shelf")` equal `if (interaction.customId == id)`.

**Note:** If you have another error, try changing your nanoid package in your package.json to version ^3.3.4, and uninstall and install it again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it is still causing the same issue. I feel like I have just messed up somewhere in the code or forgotten a vital step that's causing this issue. Cause I thought that everytime the button is called it is gonna be a new instance and it won't cause an error but I feel like I was wrong.

Comment: I may have forgotten to tell you another step, whenever you have your if (interaction.customId == "edit-shelf") try changing it to if (interaction.customId == id). If you have anymore errors, feel free to send them here and I’ll try to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now, I hope you have an amazing day!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Thanks and you too.

Comment: Instead of using the nanoid package, you could also use the id of the initial command interaction.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the trycatch block (you know, the):

```js
try {
// put your code here
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
```

im just tryna help, if it doesn't work then sorry...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).